# Intellisense Autocomplete for C# Not Working After Installing Node.js Development

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019

I've been using Visual Studio 2019 with only C# desktop development and
to type "public int" I pressed p, u, [space bar], i, n, [space bar], and that was all.

After installing Node.js development,
I have to press down arrow key and select by pressing Enter.

In short, the autocomplete suggestion is now not being applied by pressing the space bar.

Is there any preference setting that can change the way autocomplete works or
will uninstalling the Node.js/Javascript environment fix the problem?

Comment: Restart fixed it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a restart of Visual Studio resolved the author’s problem

Answer (score 0):

"Second" restart fixed it. Weird.